# Enthought canopy won't install

Tags: macos, canopy

I'm having some trouble installing Canopy on my Mac OS X (running 10.9.5) under my primary username. I get to the point where it asks for the location for the Canopy Environment Directory, but when I hit Continue, it crashes. I have been able to install it on the same computer, using my secondary username, but switching between the two usernames is less than ideal. Would love any suggestions. I already tried removing admin status from the secondary username to see if that changed anything, but it did not.

Thanks to anyone who has suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Any chance that this is relevant? https://support.enthought.com/entries/23707691-Canopy-GUI-requires-extra-setup-steps-when-user-s-home-path-contains-non-ASCII-characters

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same problem on my Mac. For me, I resolved it by changing the ownership of my home directory:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type in the following commands (hit enter after every line):

```
    cd ~
    cd ..
    sudo chown <your_username> <your_directory>
```

3. replace `<your_username>` with your username, and `<your_directory>` with the directory in which all your personal files are stored

The last command may ask for a password. If it does, enter your password and hit Enter.